# How can I add an image field to a block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to add a block containing an image field to Drupal to add it to the page layout.

I can see the image gets uploaded (because it appears in my file system), but the block forgets the image; next time I configure the block, the image I just uploaded has disappeared.

What I've got so far is the following code.

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
  $build = [];
  $build['image']['#markup'] = '';

  return $build;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://images/',
    '#title' => $this->t('Image'),
    '#description' => t("Image to show on the contact form"),
    '#default_value' => $this->configuration['image']['value'],
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
      'file_validate_size' => array(25600000),
    ),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="image_type"]' => array('value' => t('Upload New Image(s)')),
      )
    )
  );

  return $form;
}

public function blockValidate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $image = $form_state->getValue('image');
  $this->configuration['image'] = $image;
  $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($image[0]);
  $file->setPermanent();
  $file->save();
}
```

How do I display a user-uploaded image?
How do I make the block remember this picture?

Answer (score 5):

With help from "Ambidex" on Drupal Slack, I post here the complete plugin-file.

I could not find an example for this use case, and I believe it might benefit others:

file: [drupalroot]/modules/custom/ourcustomername_tweaks/src/Plugin/Block
/ContactBlock.php

.

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\ourcustomername_tweaks\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;



/**
 * Provides a 'Contact' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "contact_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Image Contact block"),
 * )
 */
class ContactBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [

        'image' => [
          'value' => ''
        ],

        'label_display' => FALSE,
      ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(){
    $build = [];


    if (  isset($this->configuration['image']) && !empty( $this->configuration['image'] )  ) {

      $image_field = $this->configuration['image'];
      $image_uri = File::load($image_field[0]);

      $build['image'] = [
        '#theme' => 'image_style',
        '#style_name' => 'ourcustomername',
        '#uri' => $image_uri->uri->value
      ];
    } else {
      $build['image']['#markup'] = '['.t('Picture').']';
    }


    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['image'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://images/',
      '#title' => $this->t('Image'),
      '#description' => t("Image to show on the contact form"),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['image'],
      '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        'file_validate_size' => array(25600000),
      ),
      '#states'        => array(
        'visible'      => array(
          ':input[name="image_type"]' => array('value' => t('Upload New Image(s)')),
        )
      )
    );

    return $form;
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    /* Fetch the array of the file stored temporarily in database */
    $image = $form_state->getValue('image');

    $this->configuration['image'] = $image;

    /* Load the object of the file by it's fid */
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load( $image[0] );

    /* Set the status flag permanent of the file object */
    $file->setPermanent();

    /* Save the file in database */
    $file->save();
  }
}
```